# how to specify menu class and id and menu container class and id using php for wordpress theame

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is  my HTML code contains `menu id` and class and also container class and id

```
<div id="ubermenu-main-33" class="ubermenu ubermenu-nojs ubermenu-main ubermenu-menu-33 ubermenu-responsive ubermenu-responsive-default ubermenu-responsive-nocollapse ubermenu-horizontal ubermenu-transition-slide ubermenu-trigger-hover_intent ubermenu-skin-none ubermenu-bar-align-full ubermenu-items-align-left ubermenu-bound ubermenu-sub-indicators ubermenu-accessible">
    <ul id="ubermenu-nav-main-33" class="ubermenu-nav">
        <li id="menu-item-4324" class="ubermenu-item ubermenu-item-type-post_type ubermenu-item-object-page ubermenu-item-4324 ubermenu-item-level-0 ubermenu-column ubermenu-column-auto" >
            <a class="ubermenu-target ubermenu-item-layout-default ubermenu-item-layout-text_only" href="index.php" tabindex="0"><span class="ubermenu-target-title ubermenu-target-text">Home</span></a>
        <ul </li>

        </ul></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4323" class="ubermenu-item ubermenu-item-type-post_type ubermenu-item-object-page ubermenu-item-4323 ubermenu-item-level-0 ubermenu-column ubermenu-column-auto" >
            <a class="ubermenu-target ubermenu-item-layout-default ubermenu-item-layout-text_only" href="about.php" tabindex="0">
                <span class="ubermenu-target-title ubermenu-target-text">About</span></a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4324" class="ubermenu-item ubermenu-item-type-post_type ubermenu-item-object-page ubermenu-item-4324 ubermenu-item-level-0 ubermenu-column ubermenu-column-auto" >
            <a class="ubermenu-target ubermenu-item-layout-default ubermenu-item-layout-text_only" href="services.php" tabindex="0">
                <span class="ubermenu-target-title ubermenu-target-text">Services</span></a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4325" class="ubermenu-item ubermenu-item-type-custom ubermenu-item-object-custom ubermenu-item-4325 ubermenu-item-level-0 ubermenu-column ubermenu-column-auto" >
        <a class="ubermenu-target ubermenu-item-layout-default ubermenu-item-layout-text_only" href="work.php" tabindex="0">
            <span class="ubermenu-target-title ubermenu-target-text">Work</span></a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-4326" class="ubermenu-item ubermenu-item-type-custom ubermenu-item-object-custom ubermenu-item-43246 ubermenu-item-level-0 ubermenu-column ubermenu-column-auto" >
        <a class="ubermenu-target ubermenu-item-layout-default ubermenu-item-layout-text_only"  href="contact.php" tabindex="0">
            <span class="ubermenu-target-title ubermenu-target-text">Contact</span></a></li>

</ul></div>
```

By using this php code i have doubt how specify the `menu id` and class and also container class and id

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>  sorry this is my required php code

Comment: did you check for wp_nav_menu() doc?

Comment: @PoovarasanRK  You can edit the post and correct it, no need to post code in comments. I edited it anyways.

Comment: <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu_class'=>'ubermenu-nav','theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id'=>'ubermenu-nav','theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>  i have specified in this way am getting menu work perfect but some styles are missing

Comment: sorry@rusty bit i really don't know how to edit my qestion

Comment: please anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

There is one tricky parameter there in `wp_nav_menu()` function, which is `fallback_cb` for firing callback function if the menu doesn't exist. So set it to `false` and you will be able to customize your output as you want. What I mean is you will be able to manage your `menu_id` and `container_id` properly.

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    // your calls
    'callback_cb' => false
));
```